# Difference between modes of literal control

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, literals

What is the difference between the passthrough and Transform modes of literal control?

Could you post an example, too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are different Literal Modes `Literal.Mode`

1. **PassThrough :** The contents of the control are not modified.
2. **Encode :** The contents of the control are converted to an HTML-encoded string.
3. **Transform :** Unsupported markup-language elements are removed from the contents of the control. If the Literal control is rendered on a browser that supports HTML or XHTML, the control's contents are not modified.

Have a look at this MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode.aspx

and take a look at this implemented example
[Use ASP.NET's Literal control to its full potential](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/programming-and-development/?p=618)

Comment: what will be the default if the `Mode` is not specified?

Answer (score 7):

If you decompile System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal.Render, you get this:

```
protected internal override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    string text = this.Text;
    if (text.Length != 0)
    {
        if (this.Mode != LiteralMode.Encode)
        {
            writer.Write(text);
        }
        else
        {
            HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text, writer);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the same for .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0.

So whatever the documentation says, there is no difference between Transform (default) and PassThrough.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. There are plenty of articles that just repeat the official documentation, but I would like to see a code sample that proves that there is a difference.

Comment: +1 I agree with you, `Transform` and `PassThrough` are treated the same way.