# Mode property of Literal control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

This may be related to this question: 
[What's the Literal control used for and what's the difference to the Label Control in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510998/whats-the-literal-control-used-for-and-whats-the-difference-to-the-label-contr)

The literal control also has three values for MODE properties:
PassThrough, Encode,Transform.

The first two are understandable but what does the third value: `Transform signify`? What kind of Transformation is being applied here to the text ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673830/difference-between-modes-of-literal-control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a question about something built into .NET, the place to check is MSDN. Here's the relevant documentation for the [Mode property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here's what is says about transform.

> Unsupported markup-language elements are removed from the contents of
>   the control. If the Literal control is rendered on a browser that
>   supports HTML or XHTML, the control's contents are not modified.

Also

> If you specify Transform, the rendering behavior of the Text property
>   depends on the type of markup being rendered. When the Literal control
>   is rendered for a device or browser that supports HTML or XHTML,
>   specifying Transform produces the same behavior as specifying
>   PassThrough. All markup tags and elements for the Text property are
>   rendered for the requesting browser.

Comment: Any example for _Unsupported markup-language elements_ ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I have no idea. But does it really matter to you? What browser doesn't support HTML or XHTML? Probably some really old phones from before the iPhone days. Seems like a legacy thing to me.

Comment: @Mason: Thanks. Can you please give any examples of : " Unsupported markup-language elements" ?

Comment: @DSimm Read my previous comment.

Comment: @Mason: I mean can you give me one example of an HTML tag? like is it any <p></p> markup or is it any <span> kind markup which  fall in category of: " Unsupported markup-language elements" ?

Comment: @DSimm When I said I don't know, I meant "I do not know". But like I said *does it matter*? Are you dealing with browsers that don't understand HTML or XHTML?

Comment: @Mason: Got the point! So this mode property will automatically take care of any such markups whatever they are. Thank you for your answer and the MSDN Link

Comment: @mason If you supply an answer so it is perfectly valid to ask :' "what you meant when you said..." If all you wanted is to supply quoted text then you should have provide a link and not an answer.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, it is valid to ask for more details. It's also valid to respond "I don't know". And no, link only answers are highly discouraged on Stack Overflow. My post answers the question, provides a link for additional detail, and provides a valuable lesson about looking up documentation.

Comment: I meant the "does it really matter to you?"  part. As of matter of fact it is :-) I was wondering what invalid tags you referenced :-) that's all.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Do you deal with browsers in 2015 that don't understand HTML or XHTML? Probably not. In which case, it's a purely academic question, which is fine. But I can't answer that.